# How to get parent of clicked element in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How to get parent of clicked (this) element in Vue.js?
In jQuery this looks like:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(2)').next('.press__news__nav--view').show();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's not a good practice in `Vue` when you're trying to manipulate DOM directly. If you want to show/hide an element, you should use `v-if` or `v-show` directives.

Anyway, you can access `event` object like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    logme: function(event) { // a regular event object is passed by $event in template
      console.log(event.target.parentElement) // parent element
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="hello">
     <button @click="logme($event)">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks wostex, it's working now. This project was specific and It's already made with jQuery. So, my job was to rewrite to Vue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Glavar If this answer worked for you, you should accept it.

Comment: Egor, would be nice if you could elaborate why manipulating the DOM directly is not a good idea.